# What is the button in the upper right of windows?

Tags: macos, keyboard, window-manager, icon

Some Mac applications have this button in the upper right. What is it called? Is there a keyboard shortcut for it?

In the case of MacVim, the button toggles the toolbar of colorful icons you see on the left. Saves some space on the screen. Is that what the button does in all applications?

[image: What is this icon?]

Comment: It's commonly called the "lozenge".

Comment: Hah! I've always wondered what's going on with that button. Thanks for asking the question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it toggles the toolbar in all applications. In many applications, it's shortcut is <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, but this is not true for all (Preview uses <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>).

Comment: Or in some cases, such as for MacVim, a shortcut isn't provided. Knowing what this button does and what it is called helped me to find [a programmatic way to access MacVim's lozenge](http://code.google.com/p/macvim/issues/detail?id=22).

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, the [Window Elements topic](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/XHIGWindows/XHIGWindows.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000961-SW8) of the Apple Human Interface Guidelines is the definitive reference here.

Answer (score 1):

In Finder windows, the lozenge also shows and hides the sidebar.