# What happened to the Finder window 'jellybean' in OS X Lion?

Tags: macos, finder

Before I updated to Lion, whenever I would mount a disk image (.dmg) the Finder window that would pop-up would always have a little 'jellybean' in the top right corner that would expand this window into a 'full' Finder window with the left-side panel, thus allowing quick and easy access to be able to eject the disk image.

[image: Where is my frakkin' jellybean?]

I do not know if this feature has been completely removed from the OS or if its just disabled. Is there a way to get this back? I miss the jellybean!

Comment: Here it is called the "lozenge" ... http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10858/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The jellybean was removed completely in Lion. However, keystroke Opt-Cmd-T or menu option View - Show Toolbar will achieve the same thing.

I miss the jellybean too!

Comment: I use opt-cmd-T for the top bid, opt-cmd-S for the side bit. Do wish the capsule was there though!

Comment: Good point, Paul. In other contexts where the jellybean toggled the toolbar, opt-cmd-T is what you need to get that functionality.

Comment: Thanks to Paul and wjv for pointing out the Toolbar shortcut. This is indeed more precisely the functionality which the jellybean gave and I have corrected my answer accordingly.

Comment: You can also find related options under 'View' in the menu bar up top.

Comment: File this one under Lion annoyances.

Answer (score 6):

Note that the lozenge or "jellybean" as you call it used to show and hide the toolbar.  Pre-Lion, it did exactly the same thing as the cmd-opt-T keyboard shortcut, and this shortcut remains in effect in Lion.

Lion adds a new cmd-opt-S shortcut which toggles only the sidebar (which is in any event displayed only when the toolbar is already present).

Answer (score 2):

It was removed completely in Lion.

To eject disk images I normally just drag the icon in the window title to the trash. Quick and simple. You can also right click on the window background and eject it via the context menu.

Comment: +1 for the right-click tip. I'll be using this when the keyboard is too far away.

Answer (score 0):

You can also eject with a keyboard shortcut:

1. Select the Finder window of the disk image (click the background to deselect anything).

   [image: Finder window showing disk image with nothing selected]
2. Press <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to eject the disk image.